# SSAS - Problem with summarizing in OLAP SSAS - diffenent than in database

Tags: ssas, olap, summarize, multidimensional-cube

I have one problem with my OLAP CUBE.
Before it was ok, but recently in my database I add a new dimension. Off course I did another import and every data in database is ok. Then I built new OLAP CUBE with all (and a new) dimensions. I thought that everything was ok. But there is one problem.
In database when I summarize one product the number of transaction is ok (equal: 2260905716), but in cube, when I am doing the same, the sum is: -2034061580. First I thouth that there is problem with data, bu in database is ok. When I connect to my base with PowerBI the summarizing is ok as well. There is onlu problem in the cube. Second: when I drilldown my product into e.g. months - sum dividing the months is ok, but total sum is wrong

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZwEd.jpg)  ---it is from OLAP CUBE brose in Visual Studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3uG5.jpg)  ---it is from my database....

Please help, I did my cube again and again, and I dont know where is the problem :-(

Thanks a lot!

elwira

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe this answer will help somebody in the future.
I didnt know what exactly happened. But I was fighting with this problem for two days.
At the and I just changed data type from integer to double, and than I processed the cube.
Problem was solved. But still I dont understand why it was only on one product, the rest was summarizing ok. Maybe sth was blocked, and change data type just unsolved it...

I dont know, but maybe it solved your problem in the future ;-)

It was problem with Integer which shows data only to sth abouve 2 bln :/
ehhhh